# Solve $8 \log(x) - x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Someone came to me recently with this seemingly simple equation to solve:

$$8 \log(x) - x = 0$$

So far, everything I have tried has been a dead end. Is there a symbolic solution to this kind of equation? If so, how do I get there?

Comment: See [*Lambert W Function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B8+Log%5Bx%5D+-+x+%3D%3D0%2C+x%5D). Regards

Comment: This really isn't a precalculus thing anymore, although it seems to be.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod: Logarithms and inverse functions are typical pre-calculus topics. It seems plausible that solving this equation might be investigated.

Comment: @robjohn I absolutely agree, but its solution involves topics not covered in precalculus. You would certainly know more than me about proper classification though, Mr. Moderator.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
8\log(x)=x\Rightarrow -x/8\ e^{-x/8}=-1/8
$$
Therefore,
$$
-x/8=\mathrm{W}(-1/8)\Rightarrow x=-8\mathrm{W}(-1/8)
$$
where $\mathrm{W}$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), the inverse to $x=we^w$.

Mathematica yields $1.1553708251000778334$, and $26.093485476611910215$ as the two real solutions: `N[-8 LambertW[0, -1/8], 20]` and `N[-8 LambertW[-1, -1/8], 20]`.

For those lacking a CAS like Mathematica, I have outlined [an algorithm to compute Lambert W](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/lambertw.html).

Comment: Or you could just use wolfram alpha, producing [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5B-8+LambertW%5B0%2C+-1%2F8%5D%2C+20%5D) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5B-8+LambertW%5B-1%2C+-1%2F8%5D%2C+20%5D).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is essentially a remote CAS.