# how to find x in $ax + e^x = k$

Tags: calculus

in my project i have faced with a formula that I can't solve it. a very simplified and basic version of that equation can be rewritten as $ax + e^x = k$. please help me to solve this elementary calculus equation.

Comment: [It's not that elementary.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations)

Comment: Your problem is a special case of the more [general problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = ax+e^x-k$, and solve $f(x) = 0$.

Newton's method would be a reasonable first start.

The update for $x$ would be $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = \frac{(x_n-1)e^{x_n}+k}{e^{x_n}+a}$.

Comment: Simpson rule seems  to  be  good then Newton's right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Simpson's rule is for quadrature, Newton's method is for root finding?

Comment: ooops,i have mixed,thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** :

1.let $\large{f(x)=\frac{k-e^x}{a}}$ by numerical method find fix point of $f$

2.
or let $\large{g(x)=ax + e^x - k}$  by numerical method find roots of $g$

Answer (score 0):

```
 myfunc=@(a,x,k) a*x+exp(x)-k;
>> a=1;
>> k=3;
>> fun=@(x) myfunc(a,x,k);
>> x=fzero(fun,0.1,k)

x =

    0.7921
```

for different value of a and k ,you get different root.or you can  use Lambert W function.thanks i hope it will help you

you dont need to use extra parameter $k$,simply do like this

```
x=fzero(fun,0.1)

x =

    0.7921
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equation can be solved with the [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) or the simpler single-valued [Wright $\omega$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Omega_function):

$$x = \frac{k}{a} - W_0(e^{k/a}/a) = \frac{k}{a} - \omega(k/a-\ln a)$$

for $x, a, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and where $W_0$ is the upper (principal) branch of the Lambert $W$ function. As @Raskolnikov suggests, these are still not "elementary," though there will be exact solutions for particular combinations of $a$ and $k$ (e.g., $x = 0$ for $a = k = 1$). See [my answer to this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417657/is-there-any-superlogarithm-or-something-to-solve-xx/417981#417981) for some suggestions on computing numeric solutions. The 2012 paper by [Lawrence, Corless, and Jeffrey](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2168773.2168779) is recommended reading if you end up needing to implement a method to evaluate the Wright $\omega$ function in part or all of the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\log(u)$ then
$$
ax+e^x=k\mapsto a\log(u)+u=k
$$
divide by $a$, exponentiate, divide by $a$ again:
$$
(u/a)e^{u/a}=\frac1ae^{k/a}
$$
The [Lambert-W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is the inverse of $x\mapsto xe^x$, so we get
$$
\begin{align}
u/a&=\mathrm{W}\left(\frac1ae^{k/a}\right)\\
u&=a\mathrm{W}\left(\frac1ae^{k/a}\right)\\
x&=\log\left(a\mathrm{W}\left(\frac1ae^{k/a}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac ka-\mathrm{W}\left(\frac1ae^{k/a}\right)
\end{align}
$$
The last formula follows from $u=e^x$ and $ax+u=k$

---

**Numerical Iteration for Lambert W**

Using Newton's method, we get the iteration
$$
w_{\text{new}}=\frac{xe^{-w}+w^2}{w+1}
$$
**Initial Values**

For the principal branch when $-1/e\le x\lt0$ and when $0\le x\le10$, use
$w=0$.  When $x\gt10$, use $w=\log(x)-\log(\log(x))$.

For the non-principal brance, if $x\in[-1/e,-0.1]$, use $w=-2$; and
if $x\in(-0.1,0)$, use $w=\log(-x)-\log(-\log(-x))$.

Comment: Please remember that $\log a \neq \ln a$, so always remember to add proper bases to the log function. You must have seen in physics textbooks where the base $e$ is omitted, but in mathematical textbooks (non calculus ones) always have mentioned that if no base is there, then 10 is assumed in such cases.

Comment: Please remember that this is a math site, so all logarithms are natural unless otherwise specified. Actually, pure math and engineering differ in the assumption about $\log(x)$: see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403836/should-i-assume-logx-to-be-log-ex-or-log-10x).

Comment: In mathematics if no base is mentioned, then it is taken with base 10, I can show you papers regarding that!

Comment: Anyone is free to use whatever convention they want. In pure mathematics, natural logs are used far more often, and so $\log(x)$ is usually assumed to be base $e$. In engineering, the base may be more often assumed to be ten.