# Is there any "superlogarithm" or something to solve $x^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there any "superlogarithm" or something to solve an equation like this:

$$x^x = 10?$$

Comment: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) works for (almost) every equations and is pretty fast (and works better for convex functions like yours).

Comment: It's usually called the Lambert W, but superlogarithm is a far better name.

Comment: In Mathematica - and no where else, as far as I know - the Lambert W is referred to as the [Product Log](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProductLog.html).

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes - it's called the [Lambert W Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Scroll down and take a look at Example 2.

Answer (score 24):

What you're looking for is the Lambert $W$ function.  This is the function such that:
$$W(xe^x) = x$$

It does not have a "simple" or explicit form.

To solve your equation, we follow this process:
$$x^x = 10$$
$$x\ln x = \ln10$$
$$e^{\ln x}\ln x = \ln10$$
$$W(e^{\ln x}\ln x) = W(\ln10)$$
$$\ln x = W(\ln10)$$
$$x = e^{W(\ln10)}$$

Answer (score 13):

The Lambert $W$ function is technically a multi-valued function. Equations such as yours can also be solved with a simpler single valued function, the [Wright $\omega$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Omega_function) (see also [Corless & Jeffrey 2002](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/wrightomega.pdf)), which is defined with respect to the Lambert $W$. The Lambert $W$ by it's definition is the natural choice for exponential functions like yours, while the Wright $\omega$ is better suited to logarithmic ones (e.g., $z = \omega+\text{ln}(\omega)$), but one can often transform between the two. In your case, the two are equivalent via:

$$x^x = a \rightarrow x = \frac{\ln a}{W_0(\ln a)} = \frac{\ln a}{\omega(\ln(\ln a))}$$

for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and where $W_0$ is the upper (principal) branch of the Lambert $W$ function.

If you happen to need numeric values, the Wright $\omega$ function may be easier and more efficient to calculate. For $z = \ln(\ln 10)) \approx 0.834032...$ (and real $z \in [-1, 2]$), the following is [an approximation for $\omega(z)$](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/wrightomega.pdf):

$$\omega(z) \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2}(z−1) + \frac{1}{16}(z−1)^2 − \frac{1}{192}(z−1)^3 − \frac{1}{3072}(z−1)^4 + \frac{13}{61440}(z−1)^5...$$

Matlab's Symbolic Toolbox has builtin support via [`wrightOmega`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/wrightomega.html), as does Maple with [`Wrightomega`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Wrightomega). Additionally, I've implemented [the Wright $\omega$ function for complex double-precision evaluation](https://github.com/horchler/SHCTools/blob/master/SHCTools/stoneholmes/private/wrightOmegaq.m) in Matlab based on a 2012 paper by [Lawrence, Corless, and Jeffrey](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2168773.2168779) – it's 3 to 4 orders of magnitude faster than performing variable precision/symbolic calculations.