# how to solve equation $x^x=5$

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function

How can I calculate the equation $x^x=5$

Is it an exponential function?

Thank you.

Comment: Take $\log$ of both sides and try to solve the resulting equation, numerically.

Comment: That is a 3-click chain to get to the original non-duplicate.

Comment: @Zook Oops!  That was one to which I had quick access.  For convenience for others: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/is-xx-y-solvable-for-x.  Let's not make this a four-click chain. :)

Answer (score -2):

x=e^{W (5 \log )}
.................

Comment: Thank you very much. But what is W?

Comment: We prefer to see answers here with some explanation.  This looks like output from a computer algebra system, especially since the function $W$ is not declared.  It would help to define what functions you're using, as well as show the process by which your answer is obtained.

Comment: @user148733 Please see [the link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417657/is-there-any-superlogarithm-or-something-to-solve-xx/417666#417666) I gave below your question, it explains the answer to the general case to your question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @user148733 W is a function namely Lambert W function and this answer is self understood.