# Solution of $x+\log(x)=c$

Tags: problem-solving

how to solve the following equation?

$x+\log(x)=n+c$,where $c$ is constant, and $n$ is positive number and allow to be infinity.

Intuitively, if let $n \to \infty$， the approximate solution will be 
$x=n+c-\log(n)$, can any one help with the exact solution?

Comment: Search up lambert W function.

Comment: Exponentiating both sides gives $x e^x = e^c$, which can be solved (more or less by definition) by the Lambert W function @AhmedS.Attaalla mentions. See this answer to the question I suggested as a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/417666/155629

Comment: OP: Please do not deface your question after people answered it and commented on it.

Comment: @Did I think deface is a too strong a word for the change OP make. the change of $\log(x)$ to $3\log(x)$ can be a legitimate one.

Comment: @achillehui AFAIAC, I can imagine no reason for the 3. But more importantly, the revision excluded Lambert W function, thus disqualifying nearly everything contributed to the page by others so far (and making the question unanswerable, but this is still another point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write that as $x\log e+\log x=n+c$

$\log xe^x=n+c$

and now you x on one side and constants on another

Comment: And Lambert the fearless function will solve it for you.