# How to find $x$ for which $(1-1/x)^x=0.01$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this  equation ?

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=0.01$$

Which expansion series can be used here ?

Comment: It is not a polynomial equation and it only can be solved numerically.

Comment: @ajotaxte can you please explain a bit more that how to approach this problem ?

Comment: $x=1.01060650\cdots$

Comment: Numeric [root finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_finding) is a large subject in numerical analysis.  It is treated in any textbook.  There are many methods.

Comment: You can use newton method , to solve it numerically , see: http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math100/notes/approx/newton.html.

Comment: @DietrichBurde can you please explain how you got this value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a polynomial equation.  There are "closed-form" solutions, but they involve the Lambert W function:

$$ x = {\frac {2\;\ln  \left( 10 \right) }{{\rm W} \left(-
\ln  \left( 10 \right)/50 \right)+2\,\ln  \left( 10 \right) }}$$

where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.  Both the principal and $-1$ branches give real solutions.

EDIT: Actually, only the principal branch, as Peter Foreman pointed out.
The numerical value is approximately $1.010606509247998$.

Slightly more generally, consider the equation $(1-1/x)^x = y$ where $0 < y < 1$, and we want $x > 1$.  Writing $y = e^{-s}$ and taking log of both sides,
$$ x \log(1-1/x) = -s $$
Let $x = s/(s-t)$ (where we want $0 < t < s$), so $1-1/x = t/s$, and the equation becomes
$$ \log(t) - \log(s) = \log(t/s) = -s/x = t-s$$
i.e.
$$ \log(t) - t = \log(s) - s $$
which we can write as
$$ t e^{-t} = s e^{-s}$$
Of course this is true for $t=s$ (but we don't want that one).  The other solution is $t = - W(-s e^{-s})$.

Comment: I'm actually quite interested as to how you rearrange the equation to get $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{\ln{(x)}}{\ln{(x)}-W(x\ln{(x)})}$

Comment: Hmm, when I plot it with Wolfram Alpha it doesn't look like it ought to have two solutions. What are the numerical value of the two real solutions you get?

Comment: The $-1$st branch does not actually give a real solution in this case. It gives complex infinity.

Comment: Ah!  A bit of a bug in Maple.  I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a very quick and dirty way for this is binomial expansion and then converting it into a function and using Newton's method to find roots.

$$ \left ( 1 - \frac 1x \right)^x  = 0.01 \\ \Rightarrow 1 + \left ( \frac {-1}{x} \right)x + \left ( \frac{x(x+1)}{2!} \right)\frac 1 {x^2} + \dots = 0.01$$

Now, use Newton's method to find the approximate roots.

Comment: +1 for the "dirty" way

Comment: Since $x$ is very close to $1$, the binomial series converges very slowly. It would be better to use [Newton's method to compute Lambert W](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/418910).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of how to get the inversion formula:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x&=\frac1{100}\tag1\\
100\left(1-\frac1x\right)&=\exp\left(\log(100)-\frac{\log(100)}{x}\right)\tag2\\
-\log(100)\left(1-\frac1x\right)\exp\left(-\log(100)\left(1-\frac1x\right)\right)&=-\frac{\log(100)}{100}\tag3\\
-\log(100)\left(1-\frac1x\right)&=\mathrm{W}\!\left(-\frac{\log(100)}{100}\right)\tag4\\
x&=\frac{\log(100)}{\log(100)+\mathrm{W}\!\left(-\frac{\log(100)}{100}\right)}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: raise both sides to the $1/x$ power and multiply by $100$
$(3)$: multiply both sides by $-\frac{\log(100)}{100}\exp\left(-\log(100)\left(1-\frac1x\right)\right)$
$(4)$: apply Lambert W
$(5)$: solve for $x$

Use the branch of $\mathrm{W}\!\left(-\frac{\log(100)}{100}\right)\ne-\log(100)$ and we get
$$
x\doteq1.0106065092479981249
$$