# How do you usually solve an equation of the form $ax = b \ln x$?

Tags: logarithms

Are there any other methods of solving equations of $ax = b \ln x $ form, or is iteration the only approach worth trying? (We now strictly suppose that $a, b \neq 0 $).

Comment: You mean exact solution or numerical approximation of a solution?

Comment: @user37238, rather an approach with the usual steps when facing equations like this.

Comment: You can always study the function $x\mapsto ax-b\ln x$ to find its root(s).

Comment: How should I start that? I'd like to know if it can be done with simply a pen and a piece of paper.

Comment: You can use the Lambert W function to find a closed form solution. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262). You can have the solution

> $$ x=-\frac{b}{a} W_k \left( -{\frac {a}{b}} \right), $$

where $ W_k(x) $ is the Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: Thank you Mhenni and thank you too, @user37238. The Lambert W function is generically a great tool for these kind of problems of mine.

Comment: @DrH: You are welcome.