# Solving for $x$ in logarithmic equation

Tags: lambert-w

Could anyone please show me how to solve for $x$ this equation:

$$1 = ax  e^{-bx}$$

If solved in terms of the Lambert $W$-function, would that be considered a concrete answer?

Comment: $$1=axe^{-bx}\implies 0=\log a+\log x-bx$$

this is not what you wrote after "or" ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, I suppose  th OP only wanted to describe the structure of the equations. $a$ and $b$ in the first equation have nothing to do with $a$ and $b$ in the second one. Maybe it would be better to take $c$ and $d$ for the second equation if this was his intention.

Comment: $\large{1 \over a} > b{\rm e}^{-b^{2}}$: NO solution.
$\large{1 \over a} = b{\rm e}^{-b^{2}}$: ONE solution: $\large x = b$. $\large{1 \over a} < b{\rm e}^{-b^{2}}$: TWO solutions: one $\large < b$ and the other one $\large > b$.

Comment: @Emilio : you should read the comments and edit your question because your second equation doesn't appear to be the same as our first.  Also please tell us what you tried.  I did not downvote it, and I don't think it merits 3 downvotes.

Comment: You can find a solution in terms of [Lambert W-function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the Lambert W-function.

The solution is:

$\displaystyle a\ne0,\quad b=0,\quad x=\dfrac1a\\\,\\a\ne0,\quad b\ne0,\quad x=-\dfrac{W_n\left( -\frac ba\right)}b,\quad n\in\mathbb Z$

Please don't hesitate to ask for further help or explanations.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. Just one question: how do I find the value of n?

Comment: Have a look at this paper (you will find it online): it will provide you with all information you need about W function. Also, you can look up the voice "analytic continuation". 
Corless, R.M.; Gonnet, G.H.; Hare, D.E.G.; Jeffrey, D.J.; and Knuth, D.E. "On the Lambert W Function." Advances in Computational Mathematics, Vol. 5, (1996): 329-359.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b\ne0$,
$$
\begin{align}
1&=axe^{-bx}\\
-\frac ba&=-bxe^{-bx}\\
\mathrm{W}\left(-\frac ba\right)&=-bx\\
-\frac1b\mathrm{W}\left(-\frac ba\right)&=x
\end{align}
$$
There is an infinite sequence of branches for Lambert-W, just as there is for logarithm. Otherwise, yes, this would be considered a concrete solution. Unless $b=0$, there is no other closed-form solution.