# Inverse of $f(x) = x + e^{2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you find the inverse of $f(x) = x + e^{2x}$ ?

I started by trying to find the inverse by replacing $f(x)$ with $y$, switching $x$ and $y$, and solving for $y$.

$$y = x + e^{2x} \implies x = y + e^{2y}$$

I took the natural log of both sides and got

$$\ln(x) = \ln(y) + 2y$$

and now I'm stuck.

Comment: First, $\ln (y+e^{2y})\neq \ln y + \ln (e^{2y})=\ln y + 2y$, so you have an error there.  Second, there is no way to get the inverse of this function using familiar functions.

Comment: Thank you! That actually helps a lot

Comment: Check the [Lamber W function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262) to solve the equation.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+x+%2B+e^%282x%29

Comment: As Mhenni Benghorbal suggested, the inverse involves a Lambert W function and the result is : x = y - W[2 e^(2y)]/2.