# How to solve $e^x=x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I mean how to solve $e^x=x$ in complex plane? Is there a solution?
I know there is no real solution to this because apparently y=x and y=$e^x$ have no interception.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha would help.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=complex+root+of+e%5Ex+-+x

Comment: See a [more general case](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks! that's great

Comment: @XiangruLian: You are welcome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$f(z)= z\cdot e^{-z}$$
is an entire function, hence the [great Picard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) gives that $f(z)$ takes any complex value (with at most one exception) infinitely often. The exceptional value is obviously zero, since $f(z)=0$ implies $z=0$, so there is an infinite number of complex numbers for which
$$ f(z) = 1,$$
i.e.
$$ z = e^z. $$
[Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) gives also that the number of zeroes of $z-e^z$ inside a region bounded by a simple closed curve $\gamma$, counter-clockwise oriented, is given by:
$$ N_{\gamma}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1-e^z}{z-e^z}\,dz.$$
Moreover, $z=e^z$ implies:
$$\|z\|=e^{\Re(z)}$$
hence all the complex solutions of $z=e^z$ lie on the curve $\gamma_+:(W(1),+\infty)\to\mathbb{C}$
$$ \gamma_+(r)=\log r+i\sqrt{r^2-\log^2 r}$$
or on the "conjugated" curve
$$ \gamma_-(r)=\log r-i\sqrt{r^2-\log^2 r}.$$

[image: Curve of the zeroes]

Comment: Thanks! Then how can I find a solution? Is it an analytic expression?

Comment: You may want to look at the Lambert W-function.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks ! I think it is solved for me:)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but i cannot figure out how the Cauchy's integral formula works when you want you find the number of zeroes.

Comment: Can you recognize what $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz$$ is ? If not, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number.

Comment: @XiangruLian: This formula works if the roots are all simple. Multiple roots are counted with their multiplicity.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: do you have any estimates from the integral of how many roots there are inside a given region (circle, square, whatever)?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I remember that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we want to solve $z=e^z$. First let's start with [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
$$
e^{x+iy}=e^x\cos(y)+ie^x\sin(y)\tag{1}
$$
Thus, we want to solve
$$
x=e^x\cos(y)\quad\text{and}\quad y=e^x\sin(y)\tag{2}
$$

---

**Locating the Roots**

From $(2)$, we get $x^2+y^2=e^{2x}$. Therefore, the roots lie on the conjugate curves
$$
y^2=e^{2x}-x^2\tag{3}
$$
The roots of $z=e^z$ will lie on $(3)$ at the intersections with the curves
$$
\cos(y)=xe^{-x}\tag{4}
$$
Note that $(4)$ says $x\le0\implies\cos(y)\le0\implies y^2\ge\pi^2/4$. However, $e^{2x}-x^2\le1$ for $x\le0$. Therefore, all root have $x\gt0$.

---

**Numerical Solution**

To solve numerically, we can solve the equation
$$
xe^{-x}=\cos\left(\sqrt{e^{2x}-x^2}\right)\tag{5}
$$
for $x$ then use $(3)$ to get $y$.

As $x$ gets large, $xe^{-x}$ gets very small. This has two consequences: from $(3)$, we get
$$
y=e^x\sqrt{1-\left(xe^{-x}\right)^2}=e^x+O\left(x^2e^{-x}\right)\tag{6}
$$
and from $(4)$, we get that $y$ is very close to an odd multiple of $\pi/2$. Thus, for large $k$, we get
$$
z_k\approx\log(k\pi+\pi/2)\pm i(k\pi+\pi/2)\tag{7}
$$

---

**Examples**

Even for $k=0$, $(7)$ is not wildly wrong. $(7)$ gives
$$
0.45158271\pm1.57079633\,i
$$
whereas using $(3)$ and $(5)$ to solve numerically gives
$$
0.31813151\pm1.33723570\,i
$$
For $k=10$, $(7)$ approximates
$$
3.49610514\pm32.98672286\,i
$$
while using $(3)$ and $(5)$ numerically gives
$$
3.49851521\pm32.88072148\,i
$$
For $k=1000$, $(7)$ approximates
$$
8.05298504\pm3143.16344992\,i
$$
while using $(3)$ and $(5)$ numerically gives
$$
8.05298751\pm3143.16088786\,i
$$

Comment: Amazing!! You are a genius

Answer (score 6):

For an answer within special functions, recall that the Lambert W function is defined as $W(z) e^{W(z)}=z$ (i.e. as the inverse function of $x e^x$.) Since the equation above can be written as $(-x)e^{-x}=-1$, we must have $x=-W(-1)$.

For consistency with Jack's result, note that the Lambert W function is an infinitely multi-valued function whose $n$-th branch is denoted by $W_n(x)$ for all integers $n$. Software, e.g., WolframAlpha can then be used to generate $-W_n(-1)$ for various $n$. Note that such solutions are all complex and occur in conjugate pairs ($-W_{1-n}(-1)=-\overline{W_{n}(-1)}$).

Answer (score 3):

There's no solution of closed form to the equation, yet it can be expressed as a special function $W(x)$, called [Lambert-W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Actually,
$$y=xe^x\quad \text{iff}\quad x=W(y)$$
Then for your equation, let $t=-x$, we have
$$1=xe^x=(-t)e^{-t}=-\frac{1}{te^t}\quad\text{iff}\quad -1=te^t$$
Hence $$x=-t=-W(-1)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!