# Closed form of the inverse of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, inverse

Does anyone know what the analytic form of the inverse of $f(x)=e^x+x$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have it in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Answer (score 2):

As it is said in previous answers, the inverse function involves Lambert $W$ function, hence non-elementary. Here I try to add some lines on how the inverse is obtained. Note that for Lambert function we have $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$. Follow the following manipulation for obtaining the inverse function $z=f^{-1}(x)$:
$$
e^z+z=x \implies z=\log(x-z) \implies \log\left((x-z)e^{x-z}\right)=x,
$$
the last equality means that $x-z=W(e^x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The analytic inverse of this function does not exist as an elementary function. Sadly. As [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20of%20x%20%2B%20e%5Ex) tells us, the inverse is $$x-W(e^x)$$ where $W$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which is not elementary.